# Integral Type expected: Python 3.5 type hinting and Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-3.5

How are user created classes supposed to be denoted in Python 3.5's type hinting?

```
from typing import List
from debt import Debt

class Debts:
    def __init__(self, debts: List[Debt]): # Expected Integral type
        self.overall = debts
```

I'm aware of typing.TypeVar, but PyCharm gives me the same error for that as well. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Pycharm are you using? As i know now pycharm does not have full support for python 3.5

Comment: @vwvolodya Pycharm 4.5 CE. It seems like it supports a great deal of the type hinting stuff right now. Maybe this is just one feature that hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm 5 has apparently shipped with full support of Python 3.5's type hinting.